# Workflow Approval Error in Second Step

Tags: workflow, error

There are two steps for the workflow. They can approve/ reject the task of the current item. But got the error once the second step is approve.

for example, when we apply the leave, firstly,the task assign to our Manager.Manager can approve/ reject the task. After, Manager approve the task assign to Boss. Currently.. if  Boss approve the task, we got the error. Error msg is "This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be edited." But there is no error when Boss rejected the task.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

It's create some task and lock it until you workflow not end. Workflow always do it. Maybe you create task in first stage? If yes try to move task creating in SecondState StateInitialization like here:

[image]